# How can I check if current day is working day

Tags: c#

I have application that needs to be run on working days, and within working hours.

In application configuration, I've set start time in format

```
Monday-Friday
9:00AM-5:30PM
```

Now, I have a problem how to check if current day is within day boundare is (for the time is easy - parse time with `DateTime.ParseExact` and simple branch will do), but I don't know how to parse days.

I've tried with:

```
DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if (day >= (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), sr.start_day) &&
    day <= (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), sr.end_day))
{ /* OK */ }
```

`sr.start_day` and `sr.end_day` are strings

but the problem occurred during weekend testing - apparently, in `DayOfWeek` `enum`, Sunday is first day of the week (refering to the comments on [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

I suppose I could do some gymnastics with current code, but I am looking for the most readable code available.

**Edit**
Sorry for the misunderstanding - working days are not from Monday to Friday - they are defined as strings in config file, and they can be even from Friday to Saturday - which breaks my original code.

Comment: Just add 7 to the end day if it is less than the start day.  Similarly, add 7 to day if it is less than the start day.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, this works! If you can, post the answer, and I will select it!

Comment: Go ahead and post the code you used and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Enums are inherently integers, but I generally advise to not use `<` or `>` for evaluation of enums. The problem is that if you ever add/remove an enum option (or reshuffle their order), you will have to scour the code to find all int-evaluations and change them. Instead, use explicit equality checks, e.g. `if(myEnumValue == MyEnum.One || myEnumValue == MyEnum.Two)` instead of `if((int)myEnumValue < 2)`. Doing it this way gives you type safety (not sure if that's the right name. I mean that deleting an enum option will yield compile time errors), less magic numbers, and better readability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment on my original question:

> Just add 7 to the end day if it is less than the start day. Similarly,
>   add 7 to day if it is less than the start day.

```
DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek start_day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), sr.start_day);
DayOfWeek end_day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), sr.end_day);

if (end_day < start_day)
    end_day += 7;

if (day < start_day)
    day += 7;

if (day >= start_day && day <= end_day)
{ 
   //Action
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is pretty controversial, otherwise a testament that C# is a language that gets the job done.  Like.

Comment: Well it answers the question I asked :-).

Answer (score 16):

```
if ((day >= DayOfWeek.Monday) && (day <= DayOfWeek.Friday))
{
    // action
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work and I think it is the same as my original code. For example, if I set up my computer on Saturday and if I set end_day to Sunday.

Comment: I see... so you don't want to know if it is a working day you want to know if it is between two strings in the variables sr.start_day and sr.end_day?

Comment: -1: While this is true for (most?) Western countries, it wouldn't work in many countries. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend.

Answer (score 5):

extention for DateTime

```
public static bool IsWeekend(this DateTime date)
    {
        return new[] {DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Saturday}.Contains(date.DayOfWeek);
    }
```

Comment: you return an array of booleans?

Comment: @Hogan Mustafa creates a new array of `DayOfWeek`instances on which he calls `Contains()` which in turn returns a `bool`. Perfectly legal. Note you'll need to import `System.Linq` for this to work though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elegant solution for the problem.  It's a class that can easily be imported into other projects.  The coding allows the programmer to dynamically assign what days to check for and pass them as a string array to the class.  The data can come from a database or be hard coded when you pass it to an instance of this class for processing.  It returns the values of True if you're off work and False if you're working that day.  Below the class I provided a simple example of implementation.  This class features:  Dynamic allocation of what days you have off, Simple error handler by setting strings to lowercase before comparing them,  Easily integrated with a database that has your work schedule where your days off may not always be the same.  Easily integrated as a hard coded number of days off.

```
// The Class To Check If You're Off Work

class DayOffChecker
{
    public bool CheckDays(List<string> DaysOff)
    {
        string CurrentDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        CurrentDay.ToLower();
        foreach (string DayCheck in DaysOff)
        {
            DayCheck.ToLower();
            if (CurrentDay == DayCheck)
            {
                return (true);
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }
}

// Example usage code:

class Program
{
    List<string> DaysOff = List<string>();
    DaysOff.Add("Saturday");  // Add some values to our list.
    DaysOff.Add("Sunday");
    DayOffChecker CheckToday = new DayOffChecker();
    if(CheckToday.CheckDays(DaysOff))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're Off Today!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also follow similar approach of checking if a given hour is between two hours. Following is the algorithm

```
checkIfFallsInRange(index,start,end)

bool normalPattern = start <= end ;

if ( normalPattern)
   return index>=start && index<=end;
else
  return index>=start || index <=end;
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution to determining if the current day is a workday or not is:

```
public static bool IsWorkDay(this DateTime dt)
{
    return IsWorkDay(dt, DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Saturday);
}

public static bool IsWorkDay(this DateTime dt, params DayOfWeek[] noneWorkDays)
{
    return !noneWorkDays.Contains(dt.DayOfWeek);
}
```

It assumes Sunday / Saturday are non-work days.  Otherwise the user can specify the non-work days.  And is an extension for easy of use.

Note: To avoid a loop could created a bit flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
DayOfWeek Day = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
int Time = DateTime.Now.Hour;
if (Day != DayOfWeek.Saturday && Day != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
 {
 if (Time >= 8 && Time <= 16)
 {
   //It is Weekdays work hours from 8 AM to 4 PM
 {
 }
else
 {
   // It is Weekend
 }
```

Comment: Please remove your twitter link. It's unwarranted. Furthermore, some explanation is warranted, answers that consist solely of a code snippet are not good answers.

Comment: Do not add your Twitter link back into this (or any other) answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DayOfWeek enumeration in order to see if a date is Sunday or Saturday. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx I hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I've asked for.

Answer (score -1):

The line below will return "Sunday"

```
string nameOfTheDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")).ToLower();

if(nameOfTheDay != "sunday" && nameOfTheDay != "saturday")
{
//Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: -1: While this is true for (most?) Western countries, it wouldn't work in many countries. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public bool IsWeekend(DateTime dateToCheck)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek) dateToCheck.Day;
        return ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)); 
    }
```

Comment: -1: While this is true for (most?) Western countries, it wouldn't work in many countries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend.